# DataBricks: Ingesting CSV data to a Delta Live Table in Python triggers "invalid characters in table name" error - how to set column mapping mode?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

First off, can I just say that I am learning DataBricks at the time of writing this post, so I'd like simpler, cruder solutions as well as more sophisticated ones.

I am reading a CSV file like this:

```py
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).load(path_to_csv_file)
```

Then I'm saving it as a Delta Live Table like this:

```py
df1.write.format("delta").save("table_path")
```

The CSV headers have characters in them like space and `&` and `/`, and I get the error:

> AnalysisException:
> Found invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=" in the column names of your
> schema.
> Please enable column mapping by setting table property 'delta.columnMapping.mode' to 'name'.
> For more details, refer to https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-column-mapping.html
> Or you can use alias to rename it.

The [documentation I've seen on the issue](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-column-mapping.html) explains how to set the column mapping mode to 'name' AFTER a table has been created using `ALTER TABLE`, but does not explain how to set it at creation time, especially when using the DataFrame API as above. Is there a way to do this?

Is there a better way to get CSV into a new table?

---

UPDATE:

Reading the docs [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#table-properties) and [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/table-properties.html), and inspired by Robert's answer, I tried this first:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.defaults.columnMapping.mode", "name")
```

Still no luck, I get the same error. It's interesting how hard it is for a beginner to write a CSV file with spaces in its headers to a Delta Live Table

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to Hemant on the Databricks community forum, I have found the answer.

```py
df1.write.format("delta").option("delta.columnMapping.mode", "name")
                         .option("path", "table_path").saveAsTable("new_table")
```

Now I can either query it with SQL or load it into a Spark dataframe:

```sql
SELECT * FROM new_table;
```

```py
delta_df = spark.read.format("delta").load("table_path")
display(delta_df)
```

### SQL Way

This method does the same thing but in SQL.

First, create a CSV-backed table for your CSV file:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_csv
  USING CSV
  OPTIONS (path '/path/to/file.csv', 'header' 'true', 'mode' 'FAILFAST');
```

Then create a Delta table using the CSV-backed table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE delta_table
  USING DELTA
  TBLPROPERTIES ("delta.columnMapping.mode" = "name")
  AS SELECT * FROM table_csv;

SELECT * FROM delta_table;
```

I've verified that I get the same error as I did when using Python should I omit the TBLPROPERTIES statement.

I guess the Python answer would be to use `spark.sql` and run this using Python, that way I could embed the CSV path variable in the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.columnMapping.mode","name")
```

In your original post, ".properties." was missing

Comment: I'd go with this answer as this was the answer posted internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option in the [Spark Configuration](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#spark-configuration) of the cluster you are using. That is how you enable the mode at runtime.

You could also set the config at runtime like this:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.<name-of-property>", <value>)
```

Comment: I've added a section to my question about what I tried (having corrected part of your answer) which unfortunately didn't work.